# How do I slide down a whole div but have it's contents stick as it's sliding?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to achieve the same blind roll down looking effect google+ has for when you click to view all comments of a post. After some searching I found: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Blind#overview but it doesn't achieve the effect I'm after.

The code alredy present in this html isn't the partial but the code that helps render the comments sown by default (2) when user enters the page. The partial comments are placed before this on click of a view all link and pushes them down. If more comments are typed before viewing all comments is clicked they are sliced off leaving the 2 most recent comments.

**html:**

```
<% if m.comments.any? %>


    <div class="allCommentsWrapper">
        <% comments(m.id).each do |comment| %>
             <div class="comment_container">
              <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_commenter(comment), :class => "commenter_photo"), commenter(comment.user_id).username %>
         <div class="commenter_content"> <div class="userNameFontStyle"><%= link_to commenter(comment.user_id).username.capitalize, commenter(comment.user_id).username %> - <%=  simple_format h(comment.content) %> </div>
            </div><div class="comment_post_time"> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago. </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>


<% end %>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.view_all_comments').off().on('ajax:success', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.post_content').find('.comment_container').slice(0, -2).remove();
    $(this).parents('.post_content').find('.comment_container:first').before("<%= j render 'users/partials/show_all_comments', :comments => @comments %>");
    $(this).parents('.post_content').find('.allCommentsWrapper').hide().show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 6000);
});
```

Anyway this doesn't achieve the effect I'm after. It's like the contents are stuck to another background and as the allCommentsWrapper div is sliding down it's revealing each comment. I want it to seem as if the comments are stuck to the div so as it's sliding down it's like the div is being pulled from the bottom but the top part of it is hidden but seems like it's just behind the divs above it.

The best way to see what I mean is visit google+ and click on e.g. "23 comments" and watch them slide down.

Would appreciate a solution and some tips if possible.

Kind regards

Comment: You're not looking for what *slideDown()* does, are you?

Comment: I've tried slideDown but the effect is different.

Comment: That's *not* HTML. Is it ASP? (Please: JavaScript needs HTML...)

Comment: @DavidThomas It's Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @DavidThomas it renders html that javascript can use.

Comment: @PatrickScott: well, yes; obviously. But it's not HTML that can be pasted into a JS Fiddle and played with, without parsing it first. And, I can't be bothered to parse RoR to try and help someone that didn't think their way through asking a question about client-side code. And, seriously, I *like* helping people; I *enjoy* Stack Overflow because of that very reason. So posting server-side code in a client-side question is somewhat irritating.

Comment: @DavidThomas Haha, sorry I wouldn't be surprised if some people didn't know that :/. I agree, that's why my example, I just faked that part, and show all the parts you'd need to solve the problem.. just change my for loop to the ajax request and resolve the promise in the ajax success callback. A little bit of tweaking to classes and done.

Comment: Completely changed my answer in an edit after opening up google plus and trying it out.. Same basic concepts, just added a recursive function with animations and promises. posted jsfiddle example

Comment: Thanks patrick. I'll give your edited example a try ..The reason I didn't provide JS Fiddle link was because I didn't have an issue I was trying to fix. I could have simply asked how do I mimic google+ show all comments js and that would be it. But.. I thought if I provided some info about my application it might help with my question. Which was really truly a how do I do question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: added code comments

http://jsfiddle.net/MZzUr/51/

How's this?

```
$("#posts").on("click", ".expander", function() {
    var commentsList = [],
        commentTemplate = $("<div/>").addClass("comment"),
        tempComment = null,
        gettingComments = new $.Deferred(),
        $this = $(this);

    // here you would probably have an ajax call
    // I just used a for loop
    // in the done or success of the ajax call, resolve addingComments
    // return an array of results and create in memory dom objects with jquery
    // $.get(url, data, function(results) {
    //    //add results to commentsList
    //    gettingComments.resolve()
    // });
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tempComment = commentTemplate.clone().text("Comment " + i);
        commentsList.push(tempComment);
    }
    gettingComments.resolve();

    gettingComments.done(function() {
        // mine were added in order created, we are going to prepend them backwards
        // so reverse the list. (easier to use in recursive function)
        commentsList.reverse();

        // pass list to recursive function to add and animate items one at a time
        AddAndAnimate(commentsList, 30, $this);
    });

    function AddAndAnimate(items, delay, $container) {
        // prepend the item, get the height, then hide it
        $container.prepend(items[0]);
        var addToHeight = "+=" + items[0].height();
        items[0].hide();

        // animate the height change of adding the element
        // when the animation is done, show the element again,
        // remove the first element from the array, and call the recursive function
        $container.animate({
            height: addToHeight
        }, delay).promise().done(function() {
            items[0].show();
            items.splice(0, 1);
            if (items.length > 0) {
                AddAndAnimate(items, delay, $container);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Here is an example of how this would be accomplished. Let me know if you need help translating that to your specific example. It's different as I don't have your ajax functions, so I mocked the adding of comments.

Comment: should probably add :first to your commentsWrapper selector too.. .find('.allCommentsWrapper:first') unless you have multiple allCommentsWrappers in each .post_content

Comment: This is the exact effect I was looking for. I'll just need to study it a bit to see how I can fit it in with my current app.